# Laravel upload images to database

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying  upload image:

View (part):

```
 <input type="file" name="image" />
```

Countoller:

```
   public function store(Request $request){
        dump($request->all());
        $this->validate($request,[
            'title'=>'required|max:255',
         //   'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            'text'=>'required',
        ]);
        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
        dump($request);
        $data=$request->all();
      dump($data);
        $aticle=new Article;
        $aticle->fill($data);
    }
```

Dump request:

```
"title" => "fgdfd"
  "alias" => "dg"
  "desc" => "fdgfgd"
  "text" => "gd"
  "image" => "IMG_0002.JPG"
  "tag" => "hg"
```

How do I put an image in MySql  database?

Answer (score 1):

[As the docs describe](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#file-uploads), you should be using the `file()` method on the `$request` to access the uploaded file, not the name of your file field.

In your case, that means:

```
// Use the file() method to access the uploaded file
$imageName = time() . '.' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

// storeAs() allows you to move a file while specifying a new filename.
// $path will be the fully qualified path to the file, including filename.
$path = $request->file('image')->storeAs(public_path('images'), $imageName);
```

It isn't clear from your question whether you want to save the file path in the database, or the actual binary file contents, as a BLOB.  Here's how to do both:

```
// Create new article
$aticle=new Article;
$aticle->fill($data);

// Either save the path to the uploaded image in the DB
$aticle->featured_image = $path;
$aticle->save();

// OR
// Save the file binary contents in the DB
$aticle->featured_image = file_get_contents($path);
$aticle->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'll save the file to a location and then store the path to that file in the database.

What version of Laravel are you on ? If you're on 5.3 or higher you can:

```
$path = $request->image->store('path/to/save/the/file');
```

this will save the file with a random name, then just store that path to the database.

or you can:

```
$path = $request->image->storeAs('path/to/save/the/file', 'filename.jpg');
```

if you want to specify the saved file name.

Answer (score 0):

This work's for me:

**Step 1**

Use Intervention Image package for manipulating images. You'll install it via composer. Run the command:

```
composer require intervention/image
```

**Step 2**

After installing Intervention Image, you need to add service providers and facade. Open our config/app.php file and add following lines. In the $providers array add the service providers for this package.

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
```

**Step 3**

Add the facade of this package to the $aliases array.

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

**Step 4**

And finally publish the configuration using following command:

```
$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravel5"
```

**Step 5 Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use DB;
use App\yourmodel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Response;
use Image;

class YourController extends Controller
{

    public function create()
    {           
        return view('yourview.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $file = Input::file('pic');
        $img = Image::make($file);
        Response::make($img->encode('jpeg'));

        $var = new YourModel;
        $var->pic = $img;
        $var->save();

        return redirect()->route('yourview.index')
                        ->with('success','Success.');
    }
```

**Step 6 View**

```
<form action="{{ route('yourview.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Image:</strong>
                <input type="file" id="pic" name="pic" class="form-control"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```