# How to correctly load image blob from mysql database in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel to display a list of items on a page. Each item has multiple images, but in this view I only want the first image to be displayed, but that doesn't really matter to the case.
I believe I stored the image correctly since I can download a `.bin` file from the database and open it in the browser, which lets me view the image correctly. This database attribute is of type `BLOB`.

So my item has a `hasMany` relation to the ItemImages table, which I try to use to access the image, but the image is never loaded and the src that is inserted is always something like `C:\xampp\tmp\php780D.tmp`.

In the controller function I just fetch the data, like so:

```
public function item_index(){
    $itemsInDatabase = Item::all();
    return view('admin.item_index')->with('items',$itemsInDatabase);
}
```

And so, in my view I access like this:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="{{$item->item_images[0]->image}}" alt="..."/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{$item->name}}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

The data reaches the view correctly, since if I dump the `$item->item_images`, it shows all ItemImages objects associated with that item. So my problem is the actual render of this image in view.

I wonder if I cannot use the relation to load the image, and I have to do some extra processing before declaring that image source attribute.

As asked by @RiggsFolly , the upload script is like this:

```
if($files=$request->file('item_images')){
    foreach($files as $file){
        $newItemImage = new ItemImage();
        $newItemImage->image = $file;
        $newItemImage->item_id = $newItem->id;
        $newItemImage->save();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: `C:\xampp\tmp\php780D.tmp` is where the file is temporarily kept when you upload the file to the server. Its deleted from there automatically when the upload script finishes. Did you save that file path into your database? Probably simplest if you show us the upload code

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did not save the path, I thought I could reach it like that. I've also edited the question to add the upload script

Comment: If the `<img>` is loaded like this `<img src="{{$item->item_images[0]->image}}" alt="..."/>` Then `$item->item_images[0]->image` must be == to `C:\xampp\tmp\php780D.tmp` So your upload and save to the database code is wrong

Comment: Are you really using Laravel 4?

Comment: Check your DB - you are saving the temporary file name, not the binary file data.  To instead save the file data as a BLOB to your DB, see eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955749/laravel-upload-images-to-database

Comment: Yes @RiggsFolly , why do you ask?

Comment: I ask about the version, because Laravel is now on V8 and even the documentation for V4 seems to have been Stored in the bin. It seems like you are still a beginner, so I would suggest using a current version so you can at least have access to a relevant manual

Comment: @RiggsFolly Not exactly a begginer but its been some time since I last worked with Laravel, and never worked with image data, only urls. I went to double check and it turns out I'm using Laravel 8. I was using "laravel --version" instead of php artisan --version, my bad. I'l correct it

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'm sorry but that post wasn't helpfull

Comment: Did you check your DB? What does the `image` field look like?

Comment: @Don'tPanic its of type BLOB

Comment: Yes, you said that in the question.  I mean what do you see stored there, are the records really BLOBs?

Comment: @Don'tPanic im not understanding the question. I've downloaded the file from the database an its a .bin file.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<img class="" src="data:image/png;base64,{{ chunk_split(base64_encode($m->blob_midia)) }}" height="300" alt="photo">
```